# Use Rspec shared examples to test a Ruby class' attributes

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec3

Trying to use a Rspec shared example to test two URL-like properties:

## spec/entity_spec.rb

```
require 'entity'
require 'shared_examples/a_url'

describe Entity do

  # create valid subject
  subject { described_class.new(name: 'foobar') }

  context ':url attribute' do
    it_behaves_like "a URL"
  end

  context ':wikipedia_url attribute' do
    it_behaves_like "a URL"
  end

end
```

## spec/shared_examples/a_url.rb

```
shared_examples_for('a URL') do |method|

    it "ensures that :#{method} does not exceed 255 characters" do
      subject.send(:method=, 'http://' + '@' * 256)
      expect(subject).to_not be_valid
    end

    it "ensures that :#{method} do not accept other schemes" do
      subject.send(:method=, 'ftp://foobar.com')
      expect(subject).to_not be_valid
    end

    it "ensures that :#{method} accepts http://" do
      subject.send(:method=, 'http://foobar.com')
      expect(subject).to be_valid
    end

    it "ensures that :#{method} accepts https://" do
      subject.send(:method=, 'https://foobar.com')
      expect(subject).to be_valid
    end

end
```

Clearly I need to send a reference to the `:url` and `:wikipedia_url` attributes to the shared example, but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shared example block takes an argument `method`, but you do not pass one to it. However, you are very close.  Just change:

```
context ':url attribute' do
  it_behaves_like "a URL", :url
end
```

Now we are passing the `:url` symbol to the shared example as `method`. Then you need to change your references to `:method=` (which will fail because it is literally `subject.method=`) to `subject.send("#{method}=", value)` so that we are actually calling the method `url=`. e.g.

```
it "ensures that :#{method} does not exceed 255 characters" do
  subject.send("#{method}=", 'http://' + '@' * 256)
  expect(subject).to_not be_valid
end
```

All that being said I would recommend changing the name of the local variable from `method` to something else (maybe even `method_name`) just to avoid confusion of the `method()` method and your local variable `method`.

[Full Example](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/CompetentMajorWeb)

Answer (score 1):

You can "provide context to a shared group using a block", as described [here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples).

```
require "set"

RSpec.shared_examples "a collection object" do
  describe "<<" do
    it "adds objects to the end of the collection" do
      collection << 1
      collection << 2
      expect(collection.to_a).to match_array([1, 2])
    end
  end
end

RSpec.describe Array do
  it_behaves_like "a collection object" do
    let(:collection) { Array.new }
  end
end

RSpec.describe Set do
  it_behaves_like "a collection object" do
    let(:collection) { Set.new }
  end
end
```